# Setting value of input from a jQuery script

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to get the `$_POST` value of an input that have the value from a jQuery script, but for some reason when I try to `var_dump` the entire `$_POST`, the field `amount` (which is the one that have the value from the script) output nothing at all.

Here's some code to your undestanding:

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    update();
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    update();
})

function update(){
    var amount2 = 0;
    var options = 0;
    $('#instNum2 option').remove();
    $('.check_list').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            amount2 += Number($(this).attr("val"));
            options ++;
        }
});

$("#amount2").val("R$"+amount2.toFixed(2));
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class="row control-group">
   <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
      <br><h4 style="margin-top: -5px;">Total Selecionado:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount2" name="amount">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

The function is simple, it sum the value of each column when selected and then it prints the total value on the input.

The problem is when I try to catch the total value of the input with generic `$_POST['amount']` after submiting the form, it prints an empty field...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are the JavaScript and PHP on the same page?

Comment: Yes it is in the same page

Comment: jQuery executes on client-side... Long after the PHP end of execution.

Comment: So what this really means? What's the solution, sorry i'm not that good in English

Comment: @FelipeS.Bueno: You are doing it the wrong way. In order to get the value on the same page, you don't need `$_POST`. You can use JavaScript for it.

Comment: No, it's not the same page, the form goes to other page where I need to print out the `$_POST` values...

Comment: How do you send the form values to the other page ? Ajax? Can you show this code ?

Comment: It's a straight up `<form action="action.php" method="POST">` and inside of that form have this input with the jQuery value

Comment: Okay!! Hey, would it be as simple as moving this line : `$("#amount2").val("R$"+amount2.toFixed(2));` inside the `update()` function ??

Comment: I moved as you said but still not showing nothing in the `var_dump` of `$_POST['amount']`

Comment: @FelipeS.Bueno where are the checkboxes? paste your complete html form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there were two errors.

**1st**: The line which updates the `#amount2` was outside the `update()` function.
**2nd**: this line fails `amount2 += Number($(this).val());`
You want the inputted value (or modified value) of this input... Not the `value attribute`'s value.

Difference is:
`$(this).attr("val")` would return something defined in the attribute like so :
 `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount2" name="amount" value="default value">`

And `$("#amount2").val()` will return the actual value.

Thy this:

```
function update(){
    var amount2 = 0;
    var options = 0;
    $('#instNum2 option').remove();
    $('.check_list').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            amount2 += Number($(this).val());
            options ++;
        }
        $("#amount2").val("R$"+amount2.toFixed(2));
        console.log($("#amount2").val());
});
```

I added a console.log for you to check if the value you want is present when executing the `update()` function.

**EDIT based on comment**

Try this in your PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['amount'])){
    echo "$_POST['amount'] is set.<br>";
    echo "It's value is: x" . $_POST['amount'] . "x";   // if it is empty, you'll get "xx" echoed.
}else{
    echo "$_POST['amount'] is NOT set.<br>";
}
```

Comment: The input works perfectly fine, the problem really is when I try to `echo` or `var_dump` the `$_POST['amount']` on the form action it returns me nothing. I did your changes and its working still, but keep showing empty on the `var_dump` or `echo`

Comment: Your test returns: `is set.xx` so I assume that somehow the form isn't getting the jQuery value from the input.

Comment: Exactly... So... When you check a checkbox, does `update()` function console logs something ?

Comment: Yes! The function is working, when I select one checkbox, it changes to `R$181,30` , when I check another it sum the value, but when I submit the form it comes empty....

Comment: Try replacing the `$` by it's HTML entity : `&dollar;`, in the script... Maybe that's the problem. Maybe not... Let's eliminate this possibility ;)

Comment: I mean `$("#amount2").val("R&dollar;"+amount2.toFixed(2));`

Comment: Done. Nothing. Assuming this script picks the id of the input, and the `$_POST` use the name tag, couldn't be it? How can I get the name tag in this script?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. As far as I know. if you want to test it in the script, try this rignt under the first console.log: `console.log(" value by Name: " + $("input[name='amount']").val() );` But I don't think it's the problem. You should get the same value.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mess. Will post the right answer right now.

Comment: ?? What? You just found that you had more than one input named "amount" ? That would have been my next question...

Comment: No, actually I was selecting the id of the input in the form, and what I needed was the name tag and not the id so the $_POST method could work properly. xD

Comment: That is strange... Since the 2 ways are supposed to select the same input  element. But... Since it now works, stop trying to fix it ! lollll ;)

Comment: Check if you have two elements with id="amount2"... ;)

Comment: Really appreciate all the effort to help me Louys. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, instead of selecting the id of the  input, just select the input name.

Before:

`$("#amount2").val("R$"+amount2.toFixed(2));`

After:

`$("input[name=amount]").val("R$"+amount2.toFixed(2));`

This will get the tag name and the `$_POST` will work just fine.